# python ZeroRPC heartbeat error on public IP

Tags: python, zerorpc

I run a ZeroRPC server and I can connect successfully with a client to the 127.0.0.1 IP. 
However when I use the public IP of the server to the client I get the following error:

zerorpc.exceptions.LostRemote: Lost remote after 10s heartbeat

I have opened the port from the firewall (using ufw on Ubuntu) but still get the same error. 
Do you have any ideas what the problem might be? 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What IP address are you binding the server onto? If you want to listen on all interfaces and all addresses, something like `tcp://0.0.0.0:4242` should work.

Comment: thanks for the answer! yes, that's the exact IP/port that I bind the server to.

Comment: `netstat -n -t -l` should show you what address and port is used for listening. It could well be some firewall configuration problem. One easy way to remove zerorpc from the equation, is to run `netcat` on the server and run a  client netcat against it.